# HttpWebRequest not working on device

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I have read some topics that contains that problem but none of the answer was useful or topic wasn't resolved at the end.

So my app is working fine on emulator but doesn't work on device (HTC Trophy it that matters somehow?). I'm catching exception like that:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass2.<EndGetResponse>b__1(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
   at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass4.<FastInvoke>b__3()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
   at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)

   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Birdaholic1.AddSighting.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__8(Object state2)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
   at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
```

What should I do? Where should I start to fix it?

Comment: Very generic error (NotFound). Is your device connected to a network?

Comment: Yes. Both via WIFI and via cable when connected to PC not working

Answer (score 1):

Checklist for things to look at:

- is the `URI`-object set with the `UriKind.Absolute` attribute?
- does my cell phone have a data connection (i.e. does other apps like Facebook, internet explorer work)?
- if so, can I open the URL in the web browser (given it's a `GET`-request) and find it?

If the answer is yes to all those questions, try with a second device if at all possible and try to recreate the problem. If it still persists, look at the server side of things, perhaps caching is screwing you up for some reason.

Happy (bug) hunting!

Comment: 1. It wasn't UriKind.Absolute but after changing still not working.
2. Everything else is working.
3. It's POST request with OAuth and it's weird here because other post methods display that I'm not authenticated and this one more times doesn't show anything than not authenticated info...

Seems that the problem is on server side (but I will try other phone anyway)